# How to compare two string values in php

Tags: php

```
<?php
$p= "php";
$P= "PHP";
echo ($p > $P);
?>
```

output: 1

it shows 1 meaning $p is greater than $P , but how are they compared i mean what are their values? and also how to display the values?

Comment: what output did you want from your *comparison*?

Comment: no,i just want to know how it works, how are the two variables being compared?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to know how it works, a simple `strcmp` and `ord` functions can help you see them. Rough example:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.ord.php 
Returns the ASCII value as an integer.

```
$p= "php";
$P= "PHP";

echo ord($p);
echo '<br/>';
echo ord($P);
echo '<br/>';
var_dump(strcmp($p, $P));
echo '<br/>';
var_dump($p > $P); // $p greater than $P
```

Output:

```
112
80
int(32) 
bool(true)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's based on each characters decimal value

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_printable_characters

Comment: scroll down to the section on **ordering** for more info

Comment: what is the value of two variables?